# Using a form within MaterialUI Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used MaterialUI's Grid in my React app to split my page into two panes. The right side has two input boxes and a submit button. I'm using `spacing={3}` to provide spacing among the inputs and the button.

Initial code - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-morning-mh302

---

Next, I used [react hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/) to add a form around the right Grid elements -
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chaum-0qgb6

**Problem:** Adding the `<form>` removes the spacing provided by the Grid. How can I wrap the input and button within `<form>` without affecting the original layout (styling/spacing provided by the Grid)?

**UPDATE:** As one of the answer suggests, I prefer not to hoist the `<form>` before the Grid.

1. I feel it is hacky to apply it to non-form elements.
2. In the future, I might have to support two forms inside the grid.

Answer (score 3):

You should have another grid container inside the form:-

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";

function onSubmit(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container spacing={2} justify="space-around">
        <Grid item xs={4} container>
          Left pane
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={7} container spacing={3}>
          <Grid xs={12} item className="rightPaneHeading">
            Right pane
          </Grid>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {/* spacing should be on this grid item container */}
            <Grid item xs={12} container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                Input 1<input name="my-input-1" type="text" ref={register} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                Input 2 <input name="my-input-2" type="text" ref={register} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Plus you can have two forms in a grid (left or right):-

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Grid container spacing={2} justify="space-around">
      <Grid item xs={4} container>
        Left pane
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={7} container>
        <Grid xs={12} item className="rightPaneHeading">
          Right pane
        </Grid>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {/* spacing should be on this grid item container */}
          <Grid item xs={12} container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              Input 1<input name="my-input-1" type="text" ref={register} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              Input 2 <input name="my-input-2" type="text" ref={register} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {/* spacing should be on this grid item container */}
          <Grid item xs={12} container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              Input 1<input name="my-input-1" type="text" ref={register} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              Input 2 <input name="my-input-2" type="text" ref={register} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Nesting the `form` element between the Grid container and item elements breaks the spacing because the container applies the spacing style only to its [direct children](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/56984eaabad285ba44a4026c038ca4787624c624/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L84).

One solution is to place the `form` element outside all the Grid elements. Furthermore, you can remove the requirement that inputs be nested in the form: specify an `id` on the `form` element and reference the `id` in each input's [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform).

Simplified example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

function onSubmit(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="my-form"></form>

      {/* Complex Grid layout omitted */}

      <input name="my-input" type="text" form="my-form" ref={register} />
      <button type="submit" form="my-form">Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't want to move the `form` way outside and prefer keep it wrapping only the input, button components. I like your second approach, but it cannot be applied if the `input` component will actually be present in a `React` component (say `<MyInputBoxComponent>`). I directly used `<input>` to simplify the example (I don't have control over the components to change to add a new `prop`)